# Is possible open a web page in a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, url, browser

in my application I need to open a webpage (ex. https://www.google.com/) in the application. With url_launcher opens the default browser eg safari or chrome.
Instead, I would like to view the web page inside, without opening an external browser
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can use the Webview package, I guess

### Example:

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
      ),
      body: const WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
```

Source: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

Comment: if i want open url when i push a button?

Comment: yes, but it's like the button doesn't work

Comment: Sure, I tested it. 
It works on Android  to me.

Comment: Have you read Readme for this package. Perhaps they changed something since the moment I integrated it into my App.
Also, that's not a good approach to DownVote my proposal from the very beginning. You just kill the desire to help someone :(

Comment: I didn't put the downvote myself. Anyway I will read the readme. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can force your `url_launcher` plugin to open the page on web view by adding the optional parameter :

```
launch('website_name',forceWebView: true);
```